# Multiple nested routes using RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create an Ember application using the RESTAdapter which goes one step beyond the usual default examples I've found so far.

I cannot get it to work for some reason, and was hoping that someone could help me.

`GET /folders => list of all folders
GET /folders/folder_id => list of all items in folder with given id
GET /folders/folder_id/item/item_id => item with given id in folder with given id`

The nested templates result in three adjacent columns: folders, items and item (from left to right).

Where items is a list of items associated with the folder selected in the folders column, and item is the selected item in the items column.

Thanks alot in advance for your help, and long live Ember!

Comment: What exactly is/isn't happening within your app?

Comment: List of folder is displayed just fine with link-to but when I click to list items, no rest request is sent and nothing is generated.

Comment: What do your `link-to`'s look like?

Comment: {{#each folder in controller}}
        {{#if folder.isLoaded}}
            {{#link-to "folder" folder class="list-group-item"}}
                {{folder.name}} ({{folder.count}})
            {{/link-to}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}

Comment: could you share the code of your `FolderRoute` and `FolderController`?

Comment: https://github.com/kgish/zmail-client

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename `FoldersFolderRoute` to `FolderIndexRoute`

I recommend using the ember chrome extension to visualise your route more easily, here's what it shows about your current app:

[image: zmail-client routes]